# Problems accessing XML files from repository

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Hi so I'm developing for Android using eclipse, and I recently cloned a repository but cannot access the XML files. When I try to open them eclipse gives me the following error:

Could not open the editor: Android XML Editor cannot process this input.

I then went to Window -> Preferences -> General -> File Associations and changed the XML editor from the default Android Common XML editor to XML Editor.

This let me see the source for the XML but not the graphic layout. It only gives me two options for Design and Source.

How can I view the XML files in a graphic layout??

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse are you using?

I'm using Juno on Mac, and on the bottom of the XML layout, there are two options - XML Layout and Graphical Layout. click on the graphical one

here's a picture:

[image]

**EDIT**

whoops, i didn't realize this was more complicated than that. here's what another guy said works:

```
"Just rename the file which shows erorr in the eclipse itself and open it. then agin close it and rename back to its original name."
```

so try that hopefully that works? hope you dont have a ton files to go through (if you do, maybe make a script to do it). here's the link if you want to follow that thread (it's really long so i only looked half way... maybe there's something better at the bottom)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15003

Comment: I run Indigo, and right that's how it normally looks for me. However, I can't view any XML files from the repository when I'm using the default Android XML editor. And when I changed the editor there isn't a graphical option...so I don't really know what to do except download another XML editor?

Comment: whoops. i misread your question. it seems like ur not the only one with this issue though...  umm... see my edited answer... By the way, if i didn't solve your problem, you shouldn't accept it :) rather, you should "upvote" it. otherwise other ppl think the answer is correct, and it'll confuse others

Comment: Haha I didn't realize I did that, but now I'm running into more problems...I updated my SDK tools and now when I try and update eclipse it says it cannot read the repository so I can't really view any XML files. I'm probably just going to rollback to the previous update though. *SIGH* And I'll check that out and see if it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yeah. previous update hopefully still works the way it did. Good luck!   :D